# ArgumentError: Error #1063

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm getting the following error after testing my Flash game's code:

*ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on RestartButton(). Expected 1, got 0.
    at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()
    at Document()*

RestartButton is the class of a MovieClip that has already been added to the stage.

Here is the section of my Document Class where the error is located in:

```
package 
{
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import RestartButton;
    import Level_2;

    public class Document extends MovieClip
    {
        public var leftKeyDown:Boolean = false;
        public var rightKeyDown:Boolean = false;
        public var upKeyDown:Boolean = false;
        public var downKeyDown:Boolean = false;
        public var onGround:Boolean = true;
        public var xSpeed:Number = 0;
        public var ySpeed:Number = 0;
        public var mainSpeed:Number = 3.75;
        public var frictionPower:Number = 0.9;
        public var jumpPower:Number = 13;
        public var gravityPower:Number = 0.5;
        public var terminalVelocity:Number = 75;
        public var levelNumber:int = 1;
        public var levelChange:Object;
        public var levelArray:Array = new Array();
        public var collisionArray:Array = new Array();
        public var deathAreaArray:Array = new Array();
        public var goalAreaArray:Array = new Array();
        public var goalHitAreaArray:Array = new Array();
        public var restartButton:RestartButton;
        public var level_2:Level_2;

        public function Document()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            restartButton = new RestartButton(this);
            level_2 = new Level_2();
            // constructor code
        }
        public function init(event:Event)
        {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,checkKeysDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,checkKeysUp);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,levelHandler);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,hitTest);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,vCamMovement);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Main);
            this.levelChange = this.level_1;
        }

//...Section Removed...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the constructor of RestartButton to be parameter-less:

```
public class RestartButton extends MovieClip
{
    public var document:Document;
    public function RestartButton()
    {
    }
    ...
}

... then in your Document class
public function Document()
{
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    restartButton = new RestartButton();
    restartButton.document = this;
    level_2 = new Level_2();
    // constructor code
}
```